# Dynamic PictureBox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've created a form with a PictureBox on it and would like to dynamically create another PictureBox on the form while the program runs (to the left of the static one). I've written this code:

```
Dim temp As PictureBox
temp = New PictureBox
temp.Image = StaticPictureBox.Image
temp.Visible = True
temp.Top = StaticPictureBox.Top
temp.Width = StaticPictureBox.Width
temp.Height = StaticPictureBox.Height
temp.Left = StaticPictureBox.Left - 20
temp.BringToFront()
```

When I run this code I can detect that the temp PictureBox does get created. However, it is not rendered onto the form. It seems like it's there but is invisible.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add it to the form's control collection:

```
Me.Controls.Add(temp)
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but still doesn't work.

I tried this and I see that temp gets added to the form's children. But, StaticPictureBox is not a child, it is a child of some Panel object that's a child of the form. So I tried this:
`code`
    StaticPictureBox.Parent.Controls.Add(temp) 

I figured it would work, but didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: @SanderSmith Your code *should* work.  I tested this on my code: `PictureBox1.Parent.Controls.Add(temp)` and it worked fine.  I would suspect something is wrong with `StaticPictureBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove that code and place a picturebox next to the other one and set:

```
newpicturebox.visible = false
```

Then whenever you have the action completed you have it change:

```
newpicturebox.visible = true
```

Comment: That works for this simplified case, but what I really need to do is create them dynamically/programmatically. I just tried to make the case simple so you wouldn't need to read 2 pages of the entire program description.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but... you got an error here:

```
temp.Left = StaticPictureBox.Left - 20
```

should be:

```
temp.Left = StaticPictureBox.right + 20
```

or:

```
temp.Left = StaticPictureBox.right
```

hope it helped.